# Can the android ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 be used agaisnt a monodroid app?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i am trying to use Robotium to drive a app written bu monodroid and it seems there is a problem in invoking the app through the test app. As it seems the robotium initialize the test and the target app using android ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and some how it seems that it get confused by the package and the main activity specified ...
i am not sure but i feel it may be due to difference in package structure in java and how the namespace is used in c# ..have any body tried robotium or nativedriver against a monodroid app?

```
I/dalvikvm(  487): DALVIK THREADS:
I/dalvikvm(  487): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(  487):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
I/dalvikvm(  487):   | sysTid=487 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
I/dalvikvm(  487):   | schedstat=( 3609087971 361797990 223 )
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:499)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at    android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.hasValidConstructor(TestGrouping.java:226)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.apply(TestGrouping.java:215)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.apply(TestGrouping.java:211)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.select(TestGrouping.java:170)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.selectTestClasses(TestGrouping.java:160)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.testCaseClassesInPackage(TestGrouping.java:154)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.addPackagesRecursive(TestGrouping.java:115)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.includePackages(TestSuiteBuilder.java:103)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:360)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4218)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
I/dalvikvm(  487):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i guess the question should be about can a java class use reflection on a C# class?

more importantly... 
Is there an implementation of some thing like android ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 which supports android instrumentation with mono droid? 
or is there a way to invoke a mono droid app using a test app that uses ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about robotium, but a member of the team has been looking into native driver, and native driver causes Mono for Android apps to break because it invokes an invocation of a Java `native` method before Mono has had a chance to initialize.

We're working on a fix, but I don't know when it will be finished and available for public use. :-(

As for Java reflecting on a C# type, that isn't currently possible. Java can invoke C# code only through [Android Callable Wrappers](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture/android_callable_wrappers), which are generated for every `Java.Lang.Object` subclass, and generates method declarations for every Java interface that is implemented and any overridden base class methods...